# How do I escape a backslash in the following regex c#

Tags: c#, regex, escaping

Here is my function, I'm trying to replace a string in a file, but c# tells me my regex is malformed.  Any ideas?

```
public void function(string fileName, string path) {
    string pathToAmmend = @"$SERVERROOT\pathpath";
    string newPath = @"$SERVERROOT\" + path;

    File.WriteAllText(fileName, Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(fileName), pathToAmmend, newPath));            
    ....
}
```

It works if i change the strings to:

```
string pathToAmmend = @"$SERVERROOT\\pathpath";
string newPath = @"$SERVERROOT\\" + path;
```

But then I have two slashes and I only want one slash.

Comment: Where did the Regex.Escape answer go ? It worked for me.

Comment: The authors deleted them, probably because they noticed that `string.Replace` is a better solution here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `\` is a special escaping character in regular expressions. You have to escape it so that it will be interpreted as a literal `\` and not an escape sequence. `$` is also a special character (an [end anchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w.aspx)), so you'll want to escape that as well.

```
string pathToAmmend = @"\$SERVERROOT\\pathpath";
```

Using `@` to create a verbatim string only means you don't have to escape the `\` for the sake of the C# compiler. You still have escape the `\` for in a regular expression pattern. Without the verbatim string this would be:

```
string pathToAmmend = "\\$SERVERROOT\\\\pathpath";
```

Of course, as [*Jon Skeet* points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17974362/1715579), for something this simple, regular expressions aren't really the best way to go here.

Comment: This string gives me a result of \$SERVERROOT\\pathpath and I would like $SERVERROOT\pathpath

Comment: @DavidFolksman The `newPath` variable doesn't have to be specially escaped like this since it's not a regular expression pattern.

Comment: Personally, I prefer `Regex.Escape` over handling such issues by hand.

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you don't actually need a regular expression at all. It sounds like you quite possibly just want [`string.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx):

```
// Split into three statements for clarity.
string input = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
string output = input.Replace(pathToAmend, newPath);
File.WriteAllText(output);
```

Only use regular expressions when you're genuinely trying to match patterns.

Comment: I was doing this, but I'm working with a configuration file for an ftpd client application that requires me to write a certain number of bytes to the file.  For some reason, when I write the text back to the file, using File.WriteAllText it adds bytes on to the end of the file, whereas if I use a regex, it overwirtes the bytes and the filesize remains the same.

Comment: You're not comparing like-with-like here - you can't compare `Regex.Replace` with `File.WriteAllText`. But if you need to write the same number of bytes to the file, that begs the question of what you want to do if the replaced text is smaller... or larger. That's a completely different question to consider than whether or not to use regular expressions. I think you're confusing the two concerns.